# Java.lang.OutOfMemory Java Heap Space JDeveloper

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I am writing an application on Java and it is throwing this error `Java.lang.OutOfMemory Java Heap Space JDeveloper`. I know that I can add `java -Xmx512m` to the command line to solve the problem. However, I need to run this application on JDeveloper. So, my Question is:

How to increase the size of the Heap on JDveloper?

Thank you,
Sami

Comment: somewhere from the run dialog of JDeveloper. But are you sure you want to use this IDE?

Comment: You might want to check for memory leaks on your application, enlarging the heap size will work to some extent only. You have some good tools for runtime analysis, I use JProfiler (www.ej-technologies.com) and I checked Yourkit (www.yourkit.com) and it seemed pretty good.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I had a memory leak and I had to increase the size too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Overview

The reasons JDeveloper can run out of memory include heap limits and large files.

## Heap Limits

Files that control the amount of memory afforded to the JVM for JDeveloper upon startup, relative to the `jdeveloper/ide/bin/` directory, include:

- jdev.conf
- ide.conf

Update these files as follows:

1. Quit JDeveloper.
2. Edit `ide.conf`.
3. Append the following

   ```
   AddVMOption -Xms256M
   AddVMOption -Xmx1024M
   ```
4. Edit `jdev.conf`.
5. Find the `AddVMOption` for the "heap size."
6. Change the values as follows:

   ```
   AddVMOption -Xmx1024M
   AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
   ```

## Large Files

JDeveloper naïvely attempts to parse files having known file extensions that are located in the project's root level directory. A sufficiently large file, such as a 3GB XML file, will cause problems. To work around this issue, create a subdirectory for the large data and move the file into it. JDeveloper will not try to find resources in arbitrary subdirectories.

Comment: for me (jdev 11.1.1.7) the files are here: **jdev.conf** - `..\jdeveloper\jdev\bin` (I added AddVMOption  -XX:MaxPermSize=512M) and the **ide.conf** - `..\jdeveloper\ide\bin` (added AddVMOption  -Xmx640M and AddVMOption  -Xms256M)

Answer (score 6):

Edit ${JDEV_HOME}\jdev\bin\jdev.conf and set the following options:

```
AddVMOption -Xmx512M
AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

then restart JDeveloper.

Answer (score 3):

If your jDeveloper doesn't start after trying the above options, reduce the size from 1024 to 768 to 512

In 'ide.conf' change

```
AddVMOption -Xms256M
AddVMOption -Xmx1024M
```

to

```
AddVMOption -Xms256M
AddVMOption -Xmx768M
```

If this also doesn't start your jDeveloper, change it to

```
AddVMOption -Xms256M
AddVMOption -Xmx512M
```

And the same goes with 'jdev.conf'